# Spark ML decisiontree classifier calls random forest methods

Tags: scala, apache-spark, machine-learning, apache-spark-mllib

I'm running the following code right now, using the classifier from the ML library :

```
val decisionTree = new DecisionTreeClassifier().setLabelCol("label").setFeaturesCol("features").setMaxDepth(7).setImpurity("gini")
val model = decisionTree.fit(df3)
val prediction = model.transform(df3)
```

And when I looked at the Spark History, here's what I see :
[image]

Why is my single decision tree using randomForest methods, did I do something wrong ? And also why are some tasks really long compared to others ? (If there is something I can do to speed it up, I would like to know)

The ML documentation doesn't give much information about this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Random forests are ensembles of decision trees

So this is same as decision tree.
If you resize your max deep from 7 to 1 it'll take less time but you'll get underfitting. Also it's based on ram size.

Comment: Ok it makes sense. Can you elaborate on the ram size part please ? I had to change some parameters such as spark.driver.memory  to get my program working.

Comment: i think you should exceed your Execution Memory or heap size. actually it's depends on your model and problem solving way

Comment: Ok thank you, I also discovered the setMaxMemoryInMB option